# Best approach to storing a lot of JSON files temporarily?

Tags: json, database, local-storage

This is the scenario.

- Two python microservices. One microservice receives a form submission which contains a number of json files a user has submitted. The second service receives a message from the first microservice saying the files are uploaded and can be scanned. Once they are scanned they are deleted.

The question relates to the first microservices. What would be the best approach to storing the json files?

Would it be locally on the server? This could be a problem if the services suddenly received a lot of submissions as each user could upload almost 40+ MB.

In this case would it make sense to use a database like mongo to hold them? Paying extra for a database and it will only hold them temporarily while they're scanned.

Would love to know your thoughts on the scenario and how would you approach it?

Comment: Save them to the host's `%TEMP%` / `/tmp` directory (that's what it's for, after-all) and run a cron job nightly to delete unused temp files.

Comment: That's one approach I was thinking of but thought it wouldn't scale very well. I think it would be ideal in a small scenario where only a few users were uploading files per day but if 2000+ users decided to use the services in a single day then roughly 80 GB would be needed ( going by the average user uploading 40 MB of json). Seems like a very large tmp directory would be needed ?

Comment: Your program should delete the files immediately after they're processed (the cron job to delete leftovers is to handle cases where your program crashes before it deletes them).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, the program should delete them immediately after processing them. In the scenario where microservice one has stored a large number of files and has caused a backlog on microservice two (which is scanning the files and then deleting them). Would temporary storage still not cause problems ? It takes a few minutes to process 40 MB of data and then to delete the files. So a backlog could be a very possible scenario. In which case the files could be sitting in TEMP for a while, hopefully less then a day.

Comment: How is that any worse than storing all of that data anywhere else? Storing short-lived blobs (Binary Large OBjects) inside a database or key-value store like _Mongo_ or _Berkeley DB_ is invariably worse than as simple files for this kind of use-case (before anyone mentions [SQLite's "35% faster" paper](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html), that's not for short-lived use-cases with lots of churn)

Comment: I note that your post is filled with a lot of **mere speculation** - where is the actual profiling or benchmarks that says you will _definitely_ have an average of 40MB per client? "could" is not the same as "will".

Comment: "How is that any worse than storing all of that data anywhere else?" I just thought that if users kept submitting files it would be too much for the tmp directory. That's why I thought mongo DB would be good for something like this.

I have nothing to show that users will definitely have an average of 40 MB. I'm just basing that figure of my own test data. Some users may have 5, 10, 15 MB etc. I could also see users having way more than 40 MB. 

This post is to just get an idea of what would be the best approach, considering all the scenarios, before I start implementing it.